# Reinstall Unity on 13.04 from Cinnamon

Tags: unity, 13.04

I am trying out Cinnamon 1.8 as my only desktop environment instead of unity. I am liking so far with customizing my desktop and adding extras. How do you get unity back with the terminal? I used this source for removing unity.

[How to completely remove Unity, and replace it with Cinnamon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292394/how-to-completely-remove-unity-and-replace-it-with-cinnamon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like:

```
sudo apt-get install unity unity-common unity-services unity-lens-* unity-scope-* unity-webapps-* gnome-control-center-unity hud libunity-core-6* libunity-misc4 libunity-webapps* appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt* overlay-scrollbar* activity-log-manager-control-center firefox-globalmenu thunderbird-globalmenu libufe-xidgetter0 xul-ext-unity xul-ext-webaccounts webaccounts-extension-common xul-ext-websites-integration nautilus nautilus-sendto nautilus-sendto-empathy nautilus-share activity-log-manager-common python-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist zeitgeist zeitgeist-core zeitgeist-datahub
```

The . files you removed in your home directory will be re-created.

You may be able to

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

After an abortive attempt to use the new ATI/AMD Catalyst driver for my notebook (my card seems too exotic) I needed to return to the onboard Intel graphics. Removing the fglrx Catalyst drivers was easy, but getting unity to play after was not. I ended up reinstalling with the following two commands. Perhaps a little over the top, but all is now well.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge unity unity-common unity-services unity-lens-* unity-scope-* unity-webapps-* gnome-control-center-unity hud libunity-core-6* libunity-misc4 libunity-webapps* appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt* overlay-scrollbar* activity-log-manager-control-center firefox-globalmenu thunderbird-globalmenu libufe-xidgetter0 xul-ext-unity xul-ext-webaccounts webaccounts-extension-common xul-ext-websites-integration
```

```
sudo apt-get install unity unity-common unity-services unity-lens-* unity-scope-* unity-webapps-* gnome-control-center-unity hud libunity-core-6* libunity-misc4 libunity-webapps* appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt* overlay-scrollbar* activity-log-manager-control-center firefox-globalmenu thunderbird-globalmenu libufe-xidgetter0 xul-ext-unity xul-ext-webaccounts webaccounts-extension-common xul-ext-websites-integration
```

Comment: Maybe you should tell us about your GPU...