# Tried Gnome 3.10 on Ubuntu 13.10. How can I get Unity back?

Tags: unity, gnome, 13.10

I am running 13.10 and installed GNOME 3.10 with the [gnome3-next ppa](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3-next) from Team GNOME, as explained in an article on [Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/09/how-to-install-gnome-310-in-ubuntu-1310.html).

How can I get back to Unity?

I did a [ppa purge](https://launchpad.net/ppa-purge) and now sort of have Unity back, but still have the GNOME boot screen, the font, the close button for windows on the right side. Also if I minimize an application, Xorg and the application have around 100% CPU usage.

[image: Screenshot]

I also tried `sudo apt-get install unity` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, but it's already up to date.

I have my home folder backed up with Déjà Dup, but I would like to avoid reinstalling and reconfiguring my whole system.

Comment: My understanding is that you got unity but on login it's still gnome session by default.  You see foot icon ( like upper right) on login screen? Click there and see what choice is there. Also try dpkg-reconfigure lightdm and choose lightdm as default desktop. Cheers.

Comment: as mentioned, the problem is solved, i ended up re-installing the system. thank you though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by re-installation.

(blah blah blah)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already used ppa purge you could now:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

or [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/313130/82517) with an added `--reinstall`:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity unity-common unity-services unity-lens-* unity-scope-* unity-webapps-* gnome-control-center-unity hud libunity-core-6* libunity-misc4 libunity-webapps* appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt* overlay-scrollbar* activity-log-manager-control-center firefox-globalmenu thunderbird-globalmenu libufe-xidgetter0 xul-ext-unity xul-ext-webaccounts webaccounts-extension-common xul-ext-websites-integration nautilus nautilus-sendto nautilus-sendto-empathy nautilus-share activity-log-manager-common python-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist zeitgeist zeitgeist-core zeitgeist-datahub
```

Comment: didn't solve it, i did reinstall it. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use-

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop unity
```

then remove what you have installed before by -

```
sudo add-apt-repository--remove ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-next
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell
sudo apt-get purge gnome-documents gnome-contacts epiphany-browser gnome-boxes gnome-shell-extensions gnome-tweak-tool bijiben gnome-clocks
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo reboot
```

hope it helped you.

Comment: didn't solve it, i did reinstall it. thank you!