# How to reinstall unity desktop on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity

I've installed gnome desktop and now I don't have unity desktop.

How can I reinstall it?

Comment: You have to remove gnome-shell and re-install unity. Last time I checked this was not possible without re-installing all of ubuntu. You can try this link - http://askubuntu.com/questions/396280/how-to-revert-unity-and-remove-gnome-desktop

Comment: How did you actually remove unity?

Comment: Perhaps this answer can also be useful http://askubuntu.com/questions/313126/reinstall-unity-on-13-04-from-cinnamon

Comment: I did not remove it, after restarting the computer I could no longer use ubuntu desktop.

Answer (score 7):

Type the following in a Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Now reboot and you should have the Unity desktop environment installed.

Comment: I get, `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-desktop : Depends: ubuntu-session but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: unity-control-center but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: unity-settings-daemon but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: xul-ext-webaccounts but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
`

Comment: Same error here :/

Comment: Why not add the dependencies to the command? Like `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-session unity-control-center unity-settings-daemon xul-ext-webaccounts` or something.

Comment: use aptitude to resolve conflicts

Answer (score 6):

For dependencies after installing something else try

```
sudo apt-get check
sudo apt-get install -f
```

It should repair all problems with dependencies or errors

Edit:

[Check this link about installing multiple environments](http://ubuntuxtreme.com/howto/how-to-change-desktop-environment-in-ubuntu-12-10/)

[Check this AskUbuntu either, maybe it could help you](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162516/switching-window-manager-desktop-environments)

Comment: it did not help. still the messages I posted in the other answer.

Comment: Can you run recovery mode option from grub menu ? Maybe it helps, dont know. Never got a problem with installing things on Linux.

Comment: No. In synaptic when trying to install ubuntu-desktop I get `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
`

Comment: the same as when you use `dpkg -i package.deb`