# Unity will not load and cannot open terminal

Tags: boot, unity

I'm lost as to how I can support a seemingly legacy bug with Ubuntu.  I'll admit that I'm still rather new to Ubuntu but I'm running 14.04 and after logging into my username I'm presented with a blank desktop.

Issue is that when trying to enter TTY I just get a black screen.  I have no way to get to a terminal to do some of the fixes I've found on the forums.  Is there a way I can just boot into terminal?  I've tried pressing shift while booting after BIOS but it still just boots into the OS.  What's weird is that at the login screen, Unity is running but after logging in, it crashes.

Comment: CTRL+ALT+F1 does get you a blank black screen, no user name prompt? That's odd. If you right-click on the desktop, do you get a context menu? If yes, you can open a terminal from there.

Answer (score 0):

So appears to be linked to the fact I installed VirtualBox which uninstalled or corrupted my Desktop!  Either way the solution I used can be found here.  I had to run in recovery and get to root shell.

[How to reinstall unity desktop on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462914/how-to-reinstall-unity-desktop-on-ubuntu-14-04)