# How can I change ubuntu GUI?

Tags: gui

[image]

I am using currently above gui, default setting of my VPS service.

But I want to use this GUI instead of above, how can I do it without reinstall whole things.

[image]

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu is your VPS providing? Looks like 10.04.

Comment: I don't know version. How can I know?

Comment: I am using 16.04.3 LTS codename : xenial

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)

Comment: Then you can do `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` to get an Ubuntu option at the login screen with this GUI. See https://askubuntu.com/a/65108/158442

Comment: then it says already the newest version, how can I change to Unity?

Comment: In your login screen there will be an icon to the right of the username. Click it and you should get a dropdown, like http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Y63m1CMK6Eo/TtX4QtJykoI/AAAAAAAAB9I/dsXTNuE-baI/s1600/login-dropdown-menu-lightdm.png

Comment: can't I do that by terminal? I can't find that menu in my gui. There is no such menu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reinstall unity desktop on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462914/how-to-reinstall-unity-desktop-on-ubuntu-14-04)