# Ubuntu studio 13.10 migrating from Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-studio

I decided to give Ubuntu Studio a try and I followed [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu%20Studio%20Upgrade%20from%20Ubuntu#temporary_information_for_updating:_.28do_not_delete.29) to install the packages from Ubuntu:

After a few days I have decided I like Ubuntu Studio better and I would like to remove the unnecessary Ubuntu staff.
Unfortunately there is not so many (recent) info out there about Ubuntu Studio.

I have done

```
apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop
```

Thanks to this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292394/how-to-completely-remove-unity-and-replace-it-with-cinnamon), I have removed unity related packages
I have found this [blog post](http://cristalinux.blogspot.com.es/2012/05/ubuntu-studio-1204-review.html) which state that Ubuntu Studio uses GNOME so anything gnome related should stay?
It seems to me Nautilus should stay?
Is it safe to remove compiz?
Zeitgeist? anything else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do a light cleanup if you use `autoremove`:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Of course, that wouldn't take it out all, so you may need bring big guns, so use `deborphan`:

```
sudo apt-get install deborphan
sudo deborphan
```

Aside from that, I don't know exactly what packages overlaps and which not, but this is the safest method to remove unused packages.