# Cinnamon won't run on *Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ppa, lightdm, cinnamon

I tried to install cinnamon on my Kubuntu 13.10, just upgraded from 13.04 without problems.

There is this ppa:
ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable

Also tried to use the non-ppa-versions (those shipped with *Ubuntu).

I get the error message from within lightdm:

```
Unable to load session 'cinnamon'
```

or

```
Unable to load session 'cinnamon2d'
```

I also deleted my gnome settings (all files/folders from my home dir) and reset cinnamon by using this command line:

```
gsettings reset-recursively org.cinnamon
```

Both didn't help. How do I get Cinnamon up and running? I'm fine with debugging. Would it be possible I did not upgrade my amd graphics driver properly?

Thanks in advance!
Ben

PS: My primary desktop is KDE, so I have no problems with unity not running - it isn't running anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a solved solution for this answer:

Make sure, you do not have `cinnamon-session` installed, by typing this command:

```
sudo apt-get install cinnamon cinnamon-session_
```

The underscore will mark cinnamon-session for removal upon installing the coorect cinnamon package.

Answer (score 0):

Cinnamon is Gnome based. If you're using KDE, you can't simply swap out one for the other. Kubuntu was designed and built around KDE, so while it's technically possible, it would be a lot of command-line work, and you could potentially leave your computer unable to boot if you're not **extremely** careful.

In fact, it's so much work, that I suspect it would probably easier just to back up your /home/ folder to a cloud service or external drive and start with a clean install of Mint right off, which comes with Cinnamon already.

If, on the other hand, you want to "keep it in the family," then start with a clean install of Unity-powered Ubuntu, then follow [the directions in the first answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292394/how-to-completely-remove-unity-and-replace-it-with-cinnamon) to replace Unity with Cinnamon.

Once you've finished the clean install of one or the other and you've verified that everything works, simply restore the contents of /home/ from wherever you backed it up to, and you're done.

Comment: Hmm, I solved it myself by just installing the cinnamon package. Before that, I was always installing the cinnamon-session package, which is being shipped by ubuntu and conflicts with cinnamon provided by that ppa. \\ \\

Now it runs just fine. Cinnamon integrates nicely into lightdm (why would it not?).

Comment: Well, on Genuine Mint, Cinnamon runs around MDM, and I tried to change my Mint 16 (Peta) Vm from MDM to LightDM and it bricked. Well, mostly. I still had the terminals (CTRL+ALT+F(1-6), but that was it. No GUI.