# After installing cinnamon ,can't change access ubuntu wallpapers

Tags: 14.04, cinnamon

After installing cinnamon by removing ubuntu 14.04 unity with steps from [This Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292394/how-to-completely-remove-unity-and-replace-it-with-cinnamon)

I am unable to see and change trusty wallpapers from control center in cinnamon.

Need help ...

Comment: Wallpapers should be in the `ubuntu-wallpapers` package.

Comment: I know that but i am unable to view background as we used to view it on unity on control center...I mean it displays nothing except add and remove buttons

Answer (score 0):

You need to click the "Add" button and add the individual files you wish to choose from.

Or, if you're feeling up to it, copy your favourite wallpapers to `$HOME/.cinnamon/backgrounds` and they'll be in the list when you open the Cinnamon background chooser/changer.

Or, even better, just make `backgrounds` a symbolic link to `/usr/share/backgrounds/` and you'll have access to all your old Ubuntu wallpapers.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, for me the problem was related to '.cinnamon' not being owned by my user.

Go to your home, type `ll` and check if the folder `.cinnamon` is owned by your user. If not, execute the following command:

```
sudo chown {your_user} .cinnamon
```

To be sure, I also created the folder `backgrounds` inside `.cinnamon`.

After these steps, it worked for me.