# How to transform an Ubuntu Unity to Ubuntu Mate?

Tags: unity, mate

I want to git rid of unity and all its applications and move to Mate, there are of course a method to install the Mate desktop environment along side Unity, but I don't want that only. I want it to be as If I have Installed the Ubuntu Mate flavour from an ISO file, I mean as if Unity didn't exist at all.

Answer (score 2):

The way you word this question the only way to do this is by re-installing from an [Ubuntu Mate](https://ubuntu-mate.org/) ISO are formatting your current installation.

By completly removing Unity you will break your system. By 1st installing Mate and then removing Unity you might break your system. Here is a method for [removing Unity](https://askubuntu.com/a/292849/15811) where someone wanted Cinnamon installed. That will work for Mate too if change the personal archive to [this](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mate-dev/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-mate).

But if those commands are not up to date you will leave traces of Unity on your system. So, to me, a re-install is the only method to meet all your demands.

Answer (score 1):

Ubunutu mate provides nice guide to replace Unity with Mate desktop.
http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/replace_unity_by_mate

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.