# How to move from Ubuntu 17.04 Unity to Mate?

Tags: unity, 16.10, mate, 17.04

I found [these instructions](http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/replace_unity_by_mate) but I am a little bit reluctant to follow them blindly because the last modification date was in 2014.

**To add context to the question:**

A week ago I upgraded from 16.10 to 17.04. [Today I read](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/04/ubuntu-18-04-ship-gnome-desktop-not-unity) that future versions of Ubuntu will come with Gnome and abandon Unity. I want to take this as an opportunity to move not to Gnome but Mate. However, I do not want to do a fresh installation but keep my existing system.

Comment: HOWTO : sudo apt install --install-suggests mate-desktop

Comment: @KnudLarsen that only gets you mate desktop environment. Ubuntu Mate comes with whole lot more - it's a set of default applications  AND desktop that matters. See my answer. Sure, it's effectivelly the same  command, but you need the right package

Comment: @ElderGeek: The OP added a link. Personally I wonder, though, if MS really meant to say that they plan to abandon Unity7. Does "back to GNOME" possibly mean that focus is moved back to Unity7?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/590627/how-to-transform-an-ubuntu-unity-to-ubuntu-mate?rq=1

Comment: @ElderGeek: Time will tell. I still hope that he just expressed himself in a sloppy manner. Otherwise he would reasonably have elaborated on that part of the post.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Moving to Mate can be done easily with

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop
```

It's a meta-package that allows you installing full Ubuntu Mate environment.