# Alt-spacebar + key combinations not working on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 17.10

I have recently upgraded from 17.04 to 17.10.

Amongst a few things that aren't working any more, the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>spacebar</kbd> combo with a keyboard key (e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>spacebar</kbd>, then <kbd>x</kbd> to maximize a window) is not working any more.

I tried changing *Settings* -> *Devices* -> *Keyboard*, since the default *Maximize window* combo with <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> doesn't even work.

This does allow me to set up a working combination of my choice, e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>, but it's not exactly what I want.

**TL;DR**

I just want to e.g. maximize a window with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>spacebar</kbd>, then <kbd>x</kbd>, as I used to in 17.04.

Comment: I reported bug about that - see [bug 1725706 at Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1725706). I recommend to use MATE DE (`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop`). Also you can try to install `gnome-panel` package to use GNOME FlashBack session.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> behavior is gone and there are no plans to bring it back.  Without boring you with details, a ton of things changed 'under the hood' in this upgrade and this feature cannot be easily reimplemented.

There is a project that aims to maintain the old Ubuntu features, the Mutiny environment in Ubuntu MATE.  You can even install it without having to completely reinstall your OS, so there is no risk of losing anything.

To install the Mutiny environment, open a terminal and run these commands, the first will prompt for your user password:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y ubuntu-mate-desktop
```

If during the install process, you see a dialog titled 'Configuring lightdm', choose lightdm from the choices.

Now reboot your system and log in.

After logging back in, use the menus in the top left to navigate to:

```
Preferences -> Look and Feel -> MATE Tweak
```

Click the Panel tab on the left and switch the first dropdown from 'Traditional' to 'Mutiny'

Now <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> should be working again :)

Feel free to ask if you need help.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Can I ask you to provide me with link to existing documentation or an official forum thread substantiating this functional change?

Comment: I didn't find any one article that touched on everything in my answer so here are a few:

Here is where Ubuntu MATE announced the new "Alt menu" feature in their Mutiny environment:
    https://ubuntu-mate.org/blog/ubuntu-mate-artful-beta2/

Here is an article about Mutiny and the fact that it aiming to provide an easy environment for those used to Ubuntu's old interface:
    http://news.softpedia.com/news/ubuntu-mate-17-10-welcomes-unity-fans-with-new-mutiny-layout-ships-with-snaps-518132.shtml

(Continued)

Comment: Here is another ask ubuntu thread where it was explained how to install Ubuntu MATE
https://askubuntu.com/questions/900561/how-to-move-from-ubuntu-17-04-unity-to-mate

Comment: Thanks for the links. What I am wondering about more specifically is whether there is an official thread coming from Ubuntu that explains how and why those seemingly basic functionalities are gone with 17.10 and the switch back to GNOME.

Comment: Oh ok, here you go.  https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/04/ubuntu-unity-is-dead-desktop-will-switch-back-to-gnome-next-year/
Here you can read about why the company decided to move away from Unity 7

Comment: I was aware of the move from Unity, my point is why the GNOME version in use doesn't support such a seemingly basic functionality, and more generally, a summary of what gets lost/gained in this desktop migration process, but I realize it might be too broad...

Comment: I'm so disappointed I'm not sure whether to upvote this answer or downvote it. I'm not in the mood to upvote anything now.

Comment: Good tip. Similar answer **[here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1073932/432173)** which covers practically all of the different options that cover this usecase.