# How to purge *all* Unity packages?

Tags: unity, apt, package-management, cinnamon

Does anyone know how to purge these packages without breaking the system?

gir1.2-unity-5.0
libunity-common
libunity-protocol-private0
libunity9
unity-asset-pool
unity-greeter

The goal is a Unity-free system. Maybe with Cinnamon.

Inspired by [How to completely remove Unity, and replace it with Cinnamon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292394/how-to-completely-remove-unity-and-replace-it-with-cinnamon)

This link http://thedarrenfiles.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-replace-unity-with-cinnamon-14.html says that gir1.2-unity-5.0, unity-asset-pool and libunity-common can be removed. Haven't tried it though.

Comment: Why bother? Why not just start with the server setup and install what you want?

Comment: Because I want to switch without starting all over again.

Comment: Why a server set up? Ubuntu minimal exists.

Comment: @Fabby wouldn't that be the other way around? Ubuntu no longer has a minimal ISO, I think.

Answer (score 0):

**First ensure you already have another Desktop Environment installed** and start a session with it.

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and copy-paste the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge gir1.2-unity-5.0 libunity-common libunity-protocol-private0 libunity9 unity-asset-pool unity-greeter
```

Comment: Thanks. Will this break anything? There is an impression that these packages are essential to the system.

Comment: They aren't. They are essential for Unity. I have already done this, I installed LXDE and removed Unity. It is safe.